# Visual Basic - Extracting Files from Location

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner when it comes to Visual Basic, and I am trying to create a program that can extract certain modified files from a flash drive according to the date Then I need to copy these certain files to a new folder.  I was wondering if anyone could help me with any examples to creating the code for Visual Basic(Visual Studio 2010).  The modified files to be extracted is according to their date assumably, if you can help Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework, I'm reluctant to provide a turnkey response. Start by learning about these classes:

[`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) -- contains methods to select and read filenames from a directory. Look at the function `EnumerateFiles` in particular. It will create a list of matching filenames for you.

[`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) -- contains methods to read and write files. Contains `Copy` method which you can use to copy a file from one location to another. Method `GetCreationTime` returns the date and time the file was created. `GetLastWriteTime` will return the date/time of the file's last modification.